# Error when adding another record to dynamic memory database

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

My task is to initialize a struct in a header with some data.  Then using pointers, add/remove data by malloc-ing bigger/smaller chunks and copying the data over.

Currently, my addRecord function doesn't work as it always seems to add the same crap (Part of record number 1):

Name =

Fire Number = attan (Seems to be part of Manhattan)

Street = ork (Seems to be part of New York)

City = cret (Seems to be part of Secret)

State = tan (Seems to be part of Manhattan)

What am I doing wrong?

My header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct structPointer{
    char name[51];
    char fireNumber[11];
    char street[26];
    char city[26];
    char state[26];
};
```

My c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myData.h"

struct structInit *sP;
struct structInit *sSP;
int recordNumber = 0;
int numberOfAccesses = 0;

int main(void) {
    sP = (struct structInit *) malloc(5 * sizeof(struct structInit));
    sSP = sP;

    memcpy(sP->name,"Adam Baum",51);
    memcpy(sP->fireNumber,"N1234",11);
    memcpy(sP->street,"Top Secret",26);
    memcpy(sP->city,"Manhattan",26);
    memcpy(sP->state,"New York",26);
    sP++;
    recordNumber++;
    memcpy(sP->name,"Adam Zapel",51);
    memcpy(sP->fireNumber,"S4321",11);
    memcpy(sP->street,"Throat",26);
    memcpy(sP->city,"Manhattan",26);
    memcpy(sP->state,"New York",26);
    sP++;
    recordNumber++;
    memcpy(sP->name,"Al Bino",51);
    memcpy(sP->fireNumber,"W1234",11);
    memcpy(sP->street,"White",26);
    memcpy(sP->city,"Anchorage",26);
    memcpy(sP->state,"Alaska",26);
    sP++;
    recordNumber++;
    memcpy(sP->name,"Anne Teak",51);
    memcpy(sP->fireNumber,"E4321",11);
    memcpy(sP->street,"Oak",26);
    memcpy(sP->city,"Woodville",26);
    memcpy(sP->state,"Wisconsin",26);
    sP++;
    recordNumber++;
    memcpy(sP->name,"Barb Dwyer",51);
    memcpy(sP->fireNumber,"N1234",11);
    memcpy(sP->street,"Keepout",26);
    memcpy(sP->city,"Kilgore",26);
    memcpy(sP->state,"Texas",26);
    recordNumber++;
    sP = sSP;

    int sel;
    while (1){
    printf("MENU\n");
    printf("=====\n");
    printf("1. Print All Records\n");
    printf("2. Print Number of Records\n");
    printf("3. Print Size of Database\n");
    printf("4. Add Record\n");
    printf("5. Delete Record\n");
    printf("6. Print Number of Accesses to Database\n");
    printf("7. Exit\n");
    printf("=====\n");
    printf("Enter selection: ");
    scanf("%d", &sel);
    printf("\n");
        switch(sel){
            case 1:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                printAllRecords(sP);
                break;
            case 2:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                fprintf(stderr,"There are a Total of %d records.\n\n", recordNumber);
                break;
            case 3:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                printSizeOfDatabase(sP);
                break;
            case 4:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                sP = sSP;
                addRecord(sP);
                break;
            case 5:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                deleteRecord(sP);
                break;
            case 6:
                numberOfAccesses++;
                fprintf(stderr,"The total number of Accesses is %d\n\n", numberOfAccesses);
                break;
            case 7:
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("Error: Input was not a valid selection.\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

int printAllRecords(struct structInit *structPointer){
    int i;
    structPointer = sSP;
    printf("All Records: \n");
    for(i=1;i<=recordNumber;i++){
    printf("Record Number: %d\n", i);
    fprintf(stderr, "Name = \%s\n", structPointer-> name);
        fprintf(stderr, "Fire Number = \%s\n", structPointer-> fireNumber);
        fprintf(stderr, "Street = \%s\n", structPointer-> street);
        fprintf(stderr, "City = \%s\n", structPointer-> city);
        fprintf(stderr, "State = \%s\n\n", structPointer-> state);
        structPointer++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int printSizeOfDatabase(struct structInit *structPointer) {
    int size = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=recordNumber;i++) {
    size += sizeof(structPointer->name);
    size += sizeof(structPointer->fireNumber); 
    size += sizeof(structPointer->street);
    size += sizeof(structPointer->city);
    size += sizeof(structPointer->state);
    structPointer++;
        }
    fprintf(stderr, "The size of the database is %d bytes.\n\n", size);
    return size;
}

int addRecord(struct structInit *structPointer){
    char entryName;
    char entryFireNumber;
    char entryStreet;
    char entryCity;
    char entryState;
    recordNumber++;
    struct structInit *theStruct;
    theStruct = (struct structInit *) malloc ((recordNumber+1) * sizeof(struct structInit));
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<recordNumber;i++){
        memcpy(theStruct->name,structPointer->name,51);
        memcpy(theStruct->fireNumber,structPointer->fireNumber,11);
        memcpy(theStruct->street,structPointer->street,26);
        memcpy(theStruct->city,structPointer->city,26);
        memcpy(theStruct->state,structPointer->state,26);
        /*if(i==recordNumber){
            theStruct++;}
        else{
            theStruct++;
            structPointer++;}*/
    theStruct++;
    structPointer++;
    }
    theStruct++;

    printf("Enter the Name of the New Record: \n");
    scanf("%s",&entryName);
    memcpy(theStruct->name,&entryName,51);
    printf("Enter the Fire Number of the New Record: \n");
    scanf("%s",&entryFireNumber);
    memcpy(theStruct->fireNumber,&entryFireNumber,11);
    printf("Enter the Street of the New Record: \n");
    scanf("%s",&entryStreet);
    memcpy(theStruct->street,&entryStreet,26);
    printf("Enter the City of the New Record: \n");
    scanf("%s",&entryCity);
    memcpy(theStruct->city,&entryCity,26);
    printf("Enter the State of the New Record: \n");
    scanf("%s",&entryState);
    memcpy(theStruct->state,&entryState,26);
    structPointer=theStruct;
    printf("Record has been added.\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int deleteRecord(struct structInit *structPointer){
    struct structInit *anotherStruct;
    anotherStruct = (struct structInit *) malloc ((recordNumber+1) * sizeof(struct structInit));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    memcpy(anotherStruct->name,structPointer->name,51);
    memcpy(anotherStruct->fireNumber,structPointer->fireNumber,11);
    memcpy(anotherStruct->street,structPointer->street,26);
    memcpy(anotherStruct->city,structPointer->city,26);
    memcpy(anotherStruct->state,structPointer->state,26);
    structPointer++;
    }
    structPointer=anotherStruct;
    recordNumber--;
    printf("Record has been deleted.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which language, C or C++? Edit the tags to reflect the correct one, they are not the same thing.

Comment: All your `memcpy`s are undefined, as are your `scanf`s in `addRecord`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sorry, Must've accidentally clicked both.

Comment: @molbdnilo Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Specerion There is a vast amount of information about how to use `scanf`, `memcpy`, and `strncpy` out there. A complete answer to this question is too long and specific for SO. I would recommend that you study and write some smaller programs for practice first.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not to be rude, but this is very unhelpful.  I've looked at countless examples and have read the C function documentation.  The reason I'm asking the question on here is because I couldn't find the information I need elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance:

The `%s` format specifier for `scanf` specifies a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`.
You're passing a pointer to *one* char.
It's just bad luck that the program doesn't crash completely.

You want

```
char entryName[51];
/* ... */
printf("Enter the Name of the New Record: \n");
scanf("%s", entryName);
```

and similar for the rest of the inputs.

Replace `memcpy` with `strncpy` - you shouldn't copy anything from outside the source object.

If you use `realloc` you can get rid of the entire copying loop when you expand your table.

Assigning to a parameter doesn't modify the value of the variable whose value you passed in.
This is as true for pointers as it is for everything else.
If you want to modify a variable, pass a pointer to it:

```
int addRecord(struct structInit **structPointer)
{
   /* ... */
   *structPointer = theStruct;
   /* ... */
}
```

You don't need to do a memberwise `memcpy` between structs - in fact you don't need `memcpy` at all, since assignment works:

```
struct structInit a = /* ... */;
struct structInit b = /* ... */;
a = b; /* OK */
```

You need to make up your mind about whether to use global variables or parameters.
In particular, `printAllRecords` disregards the value of its parameter completely.

`deleteRecord` assumes that there are five records in your table.

You can also replace `printSizeOfDatabase` with this:

```
int printSizeOfDatabase() {
    int size = recordNumber * sizeof(struct structInit);
    fprintf(stderr, "The size of the database is %d bytes.\n\n", size);
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use realloc in the add function.
  A typedef would make the program a lot easier to read.
  Please add this line to the end of  mydata.h

```
  typedef struct structPointer structInit;
```

Then before main() it becomes

structInit *sP;
   structInit *sSP;

Then  printAllRecords become :
    int printAllRecords(structInit *structPointer)

Then turn ON your debugger and READ the messages.